# Как исправить ошибку Field "' cannot be modified в delphi

Tags: база-данных, delphi, access

Коротко должно работать так:
при добавлении в базу вакансий новой записи,  она автоматом подставит код работодателя

Есть два TADODataSet, при добавлении записи в TADODataSet2 вылезает ошибка Field 'codrab' cannot be modified.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

DataSet - dsvakansii(табл вакансии) связана так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам процесс ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Перед редактированием, например после открытия датасета, попробуйте явно указать этому полю ReadOnly:=false;